# Разные IP для разных клиентов VPN

Tags: openvpn

Хочется задать каждому клиенту индивидуальный IP.

Основной конфиг(`/etc/openvpn/server.conf`):

```
local MAIN_IP
port 1194
dev tun
user nobody
group $NOGROUP
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 80.67.169.12"
push "dhcp-option DNS 80.67.169.40"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Директория с индивидуальными настройками , `i_client` | `/etc/openvpn/ccd/i_client`:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.33.1 10.8.33.2
iroute 10.8.33.0 255.255.255.0
```

Изменяется только подсетка, для каждого нового клиента - `10.8.*.0`

Правила для **IPTables**:

*Accept* - `iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`

*Для клиентов, которые не имеют специального конфига в `ccd`* - `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source PRIMARY_EXTERNAL_IP`

*Индивидуальный клиент* - `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.8.33.0/255.255.255.0" -o ens3 -j SNAT --to-source INDIVIDUAL_EXTERNAL_IP`

> Решение взято с http://unix-notes.ru/2010/04/19/raznye-vneshnie-ip-dlya-raznykh-openvpn-klientov/ Практически единственный источник.

**ВПН** отлично работает при использование стандартной конфигурации без индивидуальных конфигов. И наоборот, проходит авторизация, но попытки открыть какой-то сайтик проходят неудачно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставь iroute если действительно нужен. А вот ifconfig-push штука не очень надежная по моему опыту. Убирай. Оно выставляет IP только на одной стороне тунеля, пригождается для tap-ов, для tun лучше с пула.

Нужный параметр в конфиге уже вижу: `ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt`

Зайди в файл ipp.txt и укажи подсеть для каждого имени там. Опенвпн берет адрес оттуда. Укажи полный путь к файлу в конфигурации или ищи его в /etc/openvpn/